# How to use simple_format and auto_link to open links in new tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following line in my web aplication.

```
<%= simple_format(auto_link(@micropost.content), {}, :sanitize => false) %>
```

I tried to add the target to open the links in a new tab but it does not work.

```
<%= simple_format(auto_link(@micropost.content), {}, :sanitize => false, :html => { :target => "_blank" }) %>
```

How do I get this working? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the rails_autolink gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_autolink) ?

Comment: @Willian Yes, I have this in my gem file. gem 'rails_autolink'

Comment: Have you tried this way: auto_link(post_body, :all, :target => "_blank") ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try inside the auto_link helper, like this:

```
<%= simple_format(auto_link(@micropost.content, html: { target: '_blank' }), {}, :sanitize => false) %>
```

Comment: That is perfect @juan-fuentes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Tom Banister's answer is better as he points outs, you don't need to set sanitize to false, which seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest reversing simple_format and auto_link like so:

```
<%= auto_link(simple_format(@micropost.content), html: { target: '_blank' }) %>
```

This way you don't have to set sanitise to false

Comment: combining of `auto_link` and `simple_format` works, opening in new tab does not work!